# how to select nodes to a list type custom class

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web, telerik

I have this class:

```
Protected Class MyClass

    Public item1 As Integer = 0
    Public item2 As Boolean = False

End Class
```

Then I make a list of MyClass that will be filled with the nodes of a TreeView ( Telerik )

```
 Dim customlist As New List(Of MyClass)

 For Each node As RadTreeNode In rtv.GetAllNodes
        Dim item As New MyClass
        item.item1 = node.Value
        item.item2= node.Checked
        customlist.Add(item)
    Next
```

but I do not want to fill the list with the foreach ¿How I can do with linq ?, by example:

```
Dim customlist As List(Of MyClass) = rtv.GetAllNodes.Select(Of MyClass)(¿what code goes here?).ToList()
```

Thanks.